# Three.js text rendering issues

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am currently working on a three.js project and we are running into issues loading fonts onto our text.

We are using [TextGeometry](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Extras.Geometries/TextGeometry) object to render our fonts and the typeface js [converter](http://typeface.neocracy.org/fonts.html) to add in our fonts.

Some fonts work great but others do not perform as expected with some letters not rendering correctly such as d's and o's.

This can be seen in the fiddle below, the font is loading the interior of some letters not the exterior.

http://jsfiddle.net/264jawhe/2/

Can anyone identify why this is happening and if there is a better method to display text possibly loading an html element?

Thanks in advance!

```
var textGeom = new THREE.TextGeometry("Video Dp", 
     {
      font: 'acknowledgement',
      weight: 'normal'
     });
var material2 = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
var textMesh = new THREE.Mesh( textGeom, material2 );

scene.add( textMesh );
```

Comment: Use this fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/264jawhe/) as a starting point to show your problem.

Comment: @gaitat Updated, thank you for the fiddle!

Answer (score 1):

Please check the fiddle. Actually the issue is with your font style. I have just changed the font face and its working fine

[Refer to this Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8qrad98b/)

```
var textGeom = new THREE.TextGeometry("Video Dp", {
    font: 'optimer',
    weight: 'normal'
});
var material2 = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
var textMesh = new THREE.Mesh(textGeom, material2);
scene.add(textMesh);
```

Comment: I agree that the font is the issue but is this an issue with the converter or is there types of fonts not recommended to input?

Comment: It completely depends on the fonts you are using, Better to switch to the other font for good output, Converter works fine but different font can show different property when used in three.js 3D text

Answer (score 0):

It is related to 'Direction of Paths' of type1 fonts.

Visit [this](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/6918) . You can details about the bug with solution and a tool for using any font file for generating mesh.